# How to use DataTransferManager with MenuFlyoutItem

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, runtime

I find that **ShareLinkTask** replaced by **DataTransferManager** in PW8.1 Runtime C#,
So I try to use **DataTransferManager** with sample button and it works, but the problem with **MenuFlyoutItem**, because I try to share the content of a selected item in the **ListBox**, and this is my code

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Register the current page as a share source.
        _dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
        _dataTransferManager.DataRequested += OnDataRequested;
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Unregister the current page as a share source.
        _dataTransferManager.DataRequested -= OnDataRequested;
    }

protected void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            listitem = (e.OriginalSource as MenuFlyoutItem).DataContext as WritePadFileContent;
            e.Request.Data.Properties.Title = listitem.Name.ToString();
            e.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "Some description"; // Optional
            e.Request.Data.SetUri(new Uri(listitem.Description.ToString()));
        }
// Click Button to share Web Link
private void btnShareLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
}
```

But the problem is **OriginalSource** underline by red and the error is

> Error 2   'Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataRequestedEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'OriginalSource' and no extension method 'OriginalSource' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataRequestedEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\juste 3al faza\Contacts\Documents\WritePad SDK\WritePad_CSharpMetroSample\WritePad_CSharpSample.WindowsPhone\MainContent.xaml.cs   500 27  WritePad_CSharpSample.WindowsPhone

I use **listitem = (e.OriginalSource as MenuFlyoutItem).DataContext as WritePadFileContent;** to get the selected item defined by name and description to share it and it works with another method.

Answer (score 0):

I get my solution and it work
I set out **FrameworkElement senderElement;** it belongs to holding method for MenuFlyout,
then,

```
protected void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        WritePadFileContent datacontext = (WritePadFileContent) senderElement.DataContext;
        e.Request.Data.Properties.Title = datacontext.Name.ToString();
        e.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "Some description"; // Optional
        e.Request.Data.SetText(datacontext.Description.ToString());
    }
```